# How to fix Can not set io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement error

Tags: java, android, appium, page-factory

I am trying to use Page Factory to separate the elements from my Base Test and Test runner but when I ran it it returns an error. Can someone help me in my code?

I already tried searching on google the fix but nothing worked

public class BaseTest {

```
private final String URL_STRING = "http://127.0.0.1:7622/wd/hub";
protected URL url;
public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

private final static String APP_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.chrome";
private final static String APP_ACTIVITY_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main";

public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> init() throws MalformedURLException {
    url = new URL(URL_STRING);
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "emulator-5554");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, APP_PACKAGE_NAME);
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, APP_ACTIVITY_NAME);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Samsung");


    driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    return driver;
}
```

}

public class HomePage extends BaseTest {

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text")
public AndroidElement searchTxt;

public HomePage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(this.driver), this);
}
```

public class SampleGoogle extends BaseTest {

```
@Test
public void Sample() throws MalformedURLException {

    HomePage homePage       = new HomePage();

    homePage.init();
    homePage.setSearch("Test");
```

Expected result should be Chrome will be opened on my emulator and then Test will be written in the search bar however an error is returned when I ran the code.

> FAILED: Sample java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement field
>   com.google.HomePage.searchTxt to
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d27c0df4
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
>     at com.google.HomePage.(HomePage.java:21)     at
>   com.testcases.SampleGoogle.Sample(SampleGoogle.java:17)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

Comment: Your test creates a new instance of the page object.  That page object attempts to initialize the web elements, but the driver has not even been initialized yet.  I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same issue ,
My mistake :I used Capital 'W' in wd of appium URL(desired capabilities). Changed that to small 'w' (wd)and its working fine now